# atom package: optionally load snippet file

Tags: package, atom-editor

When creating a language package for atom, it's possible to define a `/snippets` folder. Any files in here are automatically loaded when the package is active and the context (eg: `".source.js"`) is opened in the editor.

Now I'd like to contribute to the [language-arma-atom](https://github.com/acemod/language-arma-atom) package, where there's currently 3 snippet files: I want to add a checkbox option in the package settings to NOT load one of these files.

*ie: I know how to add the option, but not how to exclude one of these snippet files.*

Comment: It seems there's no hook to optionally load snippets. See: https://github.com/atom/snippets/blob/master/lib/snippets.coffee#L81

The only way I can think of, is putting the "optional" files in a separate folder and copying them when the support option is checked in settings. I'll try this out and give an answer if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved this was create a `snippetsAvailable` folder, put the files in there (and remove the `snippets` folder)*****.

In your main package file, add to your [config schema](https://atom.io/docs/api/v1.7.3/Config):

```coffee
config:
  optionalSnippets:
    title: "My optional snippets"
    description: "Adds optional snippets to autosuggestions"
    type: "boolean"
    default: true
```

And in your package's activation do something like this:

```coffee
activate: ->
  @subscriptions = new CompositeDisposable

  # etc..

  atom.config.observe 'my-package.optionalSnippets', (checked) ->
    # For copyNewer, see note below *
    copyNewer "my-snippets", "#{__dirname}/snippets", {
      cwd: "#{__dirname}/snippetsAvailable"
    }
```

*** Note:** I used the [copyNewer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-newer) package, because it allows me to remove the `/snippets` folder, ie: it will automatically create it again. More importantly, it won't overwrite the snippets file on each package activation; Except if you updated your package with new snippets.

Obviously you'll have to write `copyNewer = require 'copy-newer'` at the top of your main file.

Also, if you choose this method, don't forget to put `/settings` in  *.gitignore*